# How do I alt+f4 in OS X? I want to close focused window

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager, shortcut

I am looking for a way to close the currently focused window using a keyboard shortcut. Effectively I want to do the same thing as the red "X" button in the top left corner, only using a keyboard. On windows/linux this is done by <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>

I know about:

- <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> - in any tabbed application such as google chrome it will close the current tab instead of current window
- <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> - will close the entire app instead of just the current window

Comment: Years later, and mac still lacks a universal way to close windows using the keyboard :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> does what you want in Safari and Chrome. I don't think it's a system-wide standard, though.

It works in Finder too so maybe it is a standard.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Comment: cmd/shift/w is a pretty much the global command for 'close all windows'. As most apps on Mac won't quit when the last window is closed, I guess this is as close as you will get, but it is not the equivalent of alt/F4, as that will quit the frontmost process. On Windows, having two windows open means you have two running processes, on Mac it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

BetterTouchTool (http://www.bettertouchtool.net) lets you assign many actions to trackpad and magic mouse gestures / mouse buttons / keyboard shortcuts. The "Close Window below cursor" action might be close to what you want

Comment: I am hesitant about installing apps outside of app store (aside of big players such as google chrome), I simply do not trust most authors

Comment: Well, I (kinda) understand that. The developer (Andreas Hegenberg, blog.boastr.net) has been developing BetterTouchTool, among other tools (some of which are also released on the app store), for more than 4 (?) years. It has been reviewed by many journalists (for example on Macworld macworld.com/article/1157058/trackpadtricks.html) and is widely used by Mac users.

BetterTouchTool is, in my opinion, a Macbook's killer "app". Many great applications (not apps, *applications*) only exist outside the app store. Being careful about what you install and from where is important, but don't miss out!

Comment: This kinda gives what you want, but note that this does not close current active window, it closes the window under the cursor. So if your cursor is hovering over a different window, the other window will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> IS what you are looking for.   It doesn't just work for tabbed applications, such as browsers.   I tested it in Finder this morning, the OS X Mail App, as well as Microsoft Word and Excel.   All of those support using the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> combination to close the current window.

Answer (score 0):

The command to close the current focused window is <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Comment: That seems to close **all** open windows in the foreground app (leaving the app running). (Tested on several apps on macOS 12 Monterey.)